# Triangle Geometry Questions

Tags: geometry

Please Help.

**Problem 1**

$M$ is the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$ and $N$ is the midpoint of $\overline{AC}$, and $T$ is the intersection of $\overline{BN}$ and $\overline{CM}$, as shown. If $\overline{BN}\perp\overline{AC}$, $BN = 12$, and $AC = 14$, then find $CT$.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE607.png)

**Problem 2**

In $\triangle ABC$, we have $AB = AC = 13$ and $BC = 10$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$ and $N$ be on $\overline{BC}$ such that $\overline{AN}$ is an altitude of $\triangle ABC$. If $\overline{AN}$ and $\overline{CM}$ intersect at $X$, then what is $AX$?

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5qnu.png)

I got $\dfrac{18}{5}$ for Problem 2, is this correct?

**Problem 3**

Altitudes $\overline{XD}$ and $\overline{YE}$ of acute triangle $\triangle XYZ$ intersect at point $H$. If the altitudes intersect at a $123^\circ$ angle, and $\angle YXH = 26^\circ$, then what is $\angle HZX$ in degrees?

Diagram: ://i.stack.imgur.com/lIDiW.png (put http in front of it) http://...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem 3 is simple.

Construction:Extend $ZH$ to $F$.Join $DF$ and $DE$.

Now, $\angle FYH=31^{\circ}$ As, $FHDY$ is cyclic, $\angle FYH=\angle FDH$ and $\angle FDH=\angle HDE$ as the altitudes bisect the angles of the pedal triangle. Now, $\angle HDE=\angle HZE=\angle HZX=31^{\circ}$ as $DHEZ$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

Your Problem 1 is trivial and is tailor made for Menelaus' Theorem.

Apply Menelaus Theorem on $\triangle ABN$ with $MC$ as transversal.

You get $\frac{AC}{NC}.\frac{TN}{BT}.\frac{BM}{AM}=1 \implies \frac{TN}{BT}=\frac{1}{2}$

Therefore $TN=\frac{1}{3}BN=4$ and $NC=7$ Therefore by Pythagoras, $TC^2=4^2+7^2=65 \implies TC=\sqrt{65}$